# Разница между присваиванием значения автосвойству и приватному полю со свойством

Tags: c#

Добрый день, столкнулся с с таким вопросом, имеется автосвойство с методом доступа get

```
public string Name {get;}
```

С помощью конструктора я присваиваю ему значение

```
public MyClass()
{
  Name = "Max";
}
```

Автосвойство успешно принимает значение, в другом случае я явно указываю приватное поле и свойство с методом доступа get

```
private string name;
public string Name; { get { return name;} }
```

Так же присваиваю значение с помощью конструктора

```
public MyClass()
{
  Name = "Max";
}
```

И в данном случае я получаю ошибку

```
Error   CS0200  Property or indexer 'MyClass.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Насколько мне известно, при использовании автосвойства приватное поле создаётся неявно, почему тогда не возникает такая же ошибка?

Comment: Магия компилятора - иначе бы вы вообще не смогли забить туда значение, даже через конструктор.

Comment: В том-то и фишка, что запись в свойство только для чтения возможна только для автосвойств, т.к их внутренности реализует компилятор и он знает как это сделать. В случае же свойства с явной реализацией это невозможно, компилятор не знает и знать не может как правильно записать в свойство при отсутствии сеттера. Такова спецификация и она документирована.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До недавнего времени возникала.

Это разрешили в шестой версии C# и код в итоге раскрывается в следующий

```
class MyClass{

    private string name;
    public string Name { get { return name;} }

    public MyClass()
    {
      name= "Max";
    }

}
```

Отсюда видно, что в конструкторе присваивается внутреннее поле, а не идет вызов самого свойства.

Comment: Автор пишет в свойство, а вы в поле. В чем смысл?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это не я пишу в поле, а компилятор так разворачивает указанный код.

Comment: А, ну да, плохо читаю :)